# onReceive on BroadCast Receiver not being called in a service

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

Thank you in advance for all your help and sorry for my English, it's my situation, i have a Broadcast Receiver that start at BOOT COMPLETED in this way:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent();
            serviceIntent.setAction("com.mypack.service.RicordaPrenotazione");
            context.startService(serviceIntent);
    }
}

<receiver android:name=".service.BootReceiver">
     <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
     </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

This broadcast receiver when the boot is completed launch this service:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONException;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;


 public class RicordaPrenotazione extends Service {

    public static final String PREFERENCES = "Pref";

    public static final String PREF_CODPAZIENTE = "codice paziente";
    public static final String PREF_NOME = "nome";
    public static final String PREF_COGNOME = "cognome";
    public static final String PREF_CF = "codice fiscale";
    public static final String PREF_TS = "tessera sanitaria";
    public static final String PREF_DATA = "data scadenza";

    private final static String LOG_TAG = "LocalService";

    private static final int NOTIFICATION = 1;

    private NotificationManager notificationManager;
    private Notification notification;
    private PendingIntent pIntent;
    private AlarmManager alarmManager;
    private Calendar calendar;

    private int notificationNumber;

String codPaziente, nome, cognome, codiceFiscale, tesseraSanitaria, dataScadenza,response;
String[] codicePrenotazione,name, surname, descEsame, descSpecialita, descAmbulatorio, descAvvertenza , dataAppuntamento, oraAppuntamento, statoPrenotazione;

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>  mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
WebService webService = new WebService();

    int numPrenotazioni;
    int count;

@Override  
    public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();

            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES,0);

            codPaziente = prefs.getString(PREF_CODPAZIENTE, "NESSUN CODICE");
            nome = prefs.getString(PREF_NOME, "NESSUN");
            cognome = prefs.getString(PREF_COGNOME, "PROFILO");
            codiceFiscale = prefs.getString(PREF_CF, "XXXXXX00X00X000X");
            tesseraSanitaria = prefs.getString(PREF_TS, "00000000000000000000");
            dataScadenza = prefs.getString(PREF_DATA, "GG-MM-AAAA");

            count = 0;

            try {

                    mylist = webService.recuperaPrenotazioni(codPaziente.trim());

            } catch (JSONException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }  

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

            super.onDestroy();
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Service Destroyed");
    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
            // Ritorno null in quanto non si vuole permettere
            // l'accesso al servizio da una applicazione diversa
            return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startid) {  

            if(mylist.isEmpty())
            {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Nessuna prenotazione trovata!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else{

                    numPrenotazioni = mylist.size();

                    for(int j=0; j<numPrenotazioni; j++){                            
                             if(mylist.get(j).get("statoPrenotazione").toString().equals("1")){
                                    count++;
                                    createAlarm(mylist.get(j).get("codicePrenotazione").toString(),mylist.get(j).get("descEsame").toString(),mylist.get(j).get("dataAppuntamento").toString(),mylist.get(j).get("oraAppuntamento").toString(),count);

                            }
                    }

            }

            // Solo per debugging
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Service Started");

            return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startid);
    }

     public void createAlarm (String codicePrenotazioneA, String descEsameA, String dataAppuntamentoA, String oraAppuntamentoA, int count)
    {

            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

            String[] temp = dataAppuntamentoA.split(" ");
            String[] temp2 = oraAppuntamentoA.split(" ");
            String[] tempData = temp[0].split("-");
            String[] tempOra = temp2[1].split(":");

            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Integer.parseInt(tempData[2]));
            cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Integer.parseInt(tempData[1]));
            cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(tempData[0]));

            cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(tempOra[0])-1);
            cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(tempOra[1]));

            String ALARM_ACTION = "com.mypack.service.MemoPrenotazione";
            Intent alarmintent = new Intent(ALARM_ACTION);

            alarmintent.putExtra("codPaziente",codPaziente);
            alarmintent.putExtra("nome",nome);
            alarmintent.putExtra("cognome",cognome);

            alarmintent.putExtra("codicePrenotazione", codicePrenotazioneA);
            alarmintent.putExtra("descEsame", descEsameA);
            alarmintent.putExtra("dataAppuntamento", dataAppuntamentoA);
            alarmintent.putExtra("oraAppuntamento", oraAppuntamentoA);
            alarmintent.putExtra("count", count);

            PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), NOTIFICATION,
            alarmintent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT|  Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);

            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);

    }

 }

<service android:name=".service.RicordaPrenotazione">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.mypack.service.RicordaPrenotazione" />
        </intent-filter>
 </service>
```

At this time all is ok, when boot is completed the broadcast receiver catch the event and launch the service, and the problem is now, this service should set a AlarmManager to a specific time and launch a pendingintent that should be catch by other broadcast receiver that create a notification, this is the code:

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MemoPrenotazione extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

    String title, note, codPaziente, nome, cognome;
    String codicePrenotazione, descEsame, dataAppuntamento, oraAppuntamento;
    int count;

    private NotificationManager manger;
    private Notification notification;
    private PendingIntent contentIntent;


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

            codPaziente = extras.getString("codPaziente");
            nome = extras.getString("nome");
            cognome = extras.getString("cognome");

            codicePrenotazione = extras.getString("codicePrenotazione");
            descEsame = extras.getString("descEsame");
            dataAppuntamento = extras.getString("dataAppuntamento");
            oraAppuntamento = extras.getString("oraAppuntamento");
            count = extras.getInt("count");

            title = "Memo Prenotazione";
            note = descEsame + " il " + dataAppuntamento + " alle "
                            + oraAppuntamento;

            manger = (NotificationManager) context
                            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            int icon = R.drawable.icon;
            CharSequence tickerText = "Memo prenotazione";
            long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

            notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);

            Intent i = new Intent(context, HttpGetTaskActivity.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();

            b.putString("codPaziente", codPaziente);
            b.putString("nome", nome);
            b.putString("cognome", cognome);

            i.putExtras(b);

            contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, NOTIFICATION_ID, i,
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, note, contentIntent);

            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND; // Suona
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS; // LED
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE; // Vibra

            manger.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

    }
 }

<receiver android:name=".service.MemoPrenotazione">
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="com.mypack.service.MemoPrenotazione" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I think that the problem is that the last broadcast receive is not being called correctly because the notification is not created.
Someone could help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare MemoPrenotazione as a BroadcastReceiver in your AndroidManifest.xml.

Check [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html) to see what you need to add.

EDIT:

In createAlarm do this instead:

```
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, MemoPrenotazione.class);
```

This will explicitly direct the broadcast to your class.

This also means you can specify the manifest like this:

```
<receiver android:name=".service.MemoPrenotazione" />
```

as you don't need the filter now you are explicitly directing the broadcast.

Comment: I do this in my manifest:

<receiver android:name=".service.MemoPrenotazione">
   <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="com.mypack.service.MemoPrenotazione" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
                                                                 It's not correct?

Comment: I can't see the package definition in your source files, what is it? I don't think you need the .service part in the names. name=".MemoPrenotazione" and name=".BootReceiver" should work.

Comment: My package is:   package com.mypackage.service; for this reason i need .service part in the names

Comment: If you have the same package in all your source files then you don't need the .service part. I think currently it will be resolving the names as com.mypackage.service.service.MemoPrenotazione which is wrong.

Comment: my situation is this: com.mypackage. and i have 3 folder remote,util,service and some activity in root folder....inside the service folder the are BootReceiver.java, MemoPrenotazione.java and RicordaPrenotazione.java...only MemoPrenotazione doesn't work

Comment: Check my edit. Directing your broadcast explicitly should make this work a lot easier than trying to direct it implicitly based on the action.

Comment: I have do this:                                                  Intent alarmintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MemoPrenotazione.class);                                          But doesn't work, i don't understand...there is other way to do what i need?

Comment: My app show the booking of customer, when the customer confirm the booking i would generate a notification to remember at customer the date and the time of the booking. My idea was, start a service when the boot completed that talk with a webservice to take all booking of customer and choose which have been confirmed. After this, take date a time of these booking and generate a notification one hour before for example.

Comment: Did you also remove the intent-filter on your receiver definition in the manifest?